# RethinkDB - Automatically generating primary keys that are linear

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, rethinkdb-python

Is there a way to make rethinkdb generate primary key automatically and to ensure the key is in an increasing order., like say 1 to n

I know when we insert a row into rethinkdb it automatically generates a primary key and returns a variable generated_keys, but I want a primary key which increases in a linear fashion say like starting from 4000 to n or 5000 to n, so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware if it is possible with RethinkDB. However, I know that it is not a feature that would scale well in a cluster of DB servers as it would introduce a bottle neck in the inserts commands.

It is always possible to do it by hand however, simply by providing an `id` field to the documents you are inserting in the tables.

Comment: Hi Vincent, you are right after googling lot more I figured the response. primary_key is auto generated and starting from a fixed value is not possible, though when we import dataset we can specify some unique field as primary key.